# NopCommerce 3.3 Add link for custom Plugin Action in ProductTemplate.Simple.cshtml, unable to find Controller and model of same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

We had created a Custom Plugin , The Nop.Web Site provided to us by our Client did not had Controller, models, Nop.Web.cs project. Initially We did not require to access much of the Nop.Web project as everything was managed through Plugin

But now there was need to add a custom Link on the ProductTemplate.Simple.cshtml view of Nop.Web/Themes/Motion/View/Catalog

Link was to add the product into a custom registry Cart.

The link access ActionResult from "Catalog" Controller supposed to be in Nop.Web Controller.

I need to pass it our Custom Plugin Controller and Action Result. But it throws error as it cannot find the controller nor "Our Custom Plugin Controller" neither the "Catalog" controller.

Can anyone suggest us solution to achieve this in better way.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you open your controller action in a separate window? Are you sure it's valid?
2. Have you looked at widgets which are supported by nopCommerce? This way you won't need to edit the cshtml file